# Bash scripting check condition

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm new to bash scripting and trying to write the following simple

```
function wait_some {
    if [ -z $1 ];
        echo some_string
        then if ! [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]];
        then
            echo "$1 is not a number"
            exit 2
        else echo "it's a number"
        fi
    fi
}

wait_some 2.2 //prints some_string and then it's a number
```

And this works as expected.

But if I delete echo "some string' it prints nothing:

```
function wait_some {
    if [ -z $1 ];
        then if ! [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]];
        then
            echo "$1 is not a number"
            exit 2
        else echo "it's a number"
        fi
    fi
}

wait_some 2.2 //prints nothing
```

Why? Why does deleting `echo some_string` right after the condition checking breaks the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the `if-condition` is executed as a compound statement in `bash` i.e. *`command1`*;*`command2`* and also incorrect usage of `-z` in the test operator.

I will explain it with the debugging I did with the `set -x` option for both the examples.

For the successful, this is what the execution sequence is

```
++ wait_some 2.2
++ '[' -z 2.2 ']'
++ echo some_string
some_string
```

As you can see the two-conditions getting executed `[ -z 2.2 ]` is failing. But why? Because the string has a non-zero length ([See how `-z` works](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)) and the check is yielding a failure of the condition, which should have been `[ ! -z 2.2 ]`. And it does not end at that.

Because of the combined set of commands you have used, *`command1`*;*`command2`* the *`command1`* the failing `if-condition`, now *`command2`* which is just a plain `echo` runs successfully with a positive return code making the overall `if-condition` successful, leading to the regex search and you are able to see the subsequent `echo'ed` statement.

Now for the failure case, the expanded result from `set -x` looks like

```
++ wait_some 2.2
++ '[' -z 2.2 ']'
```

As you can see, on removing the `echo` statement, the overall return code for the `if-condition` has become false and the inner conditions are not exercised at all. Also removing the `echo` statement is similar to actually adding a `false` operator in the script like

```
if [ -z $1 ];
    false
```

which would have expanded into

```
++ wait_some 2.2
++ '[' -z 2.2 ']'
++ false
```

leading to the failure of your condition. The ideal way your script should have been coded is something like

```
#/bin/bash

# See the updated if-condition and code reorganization

function wait_some { 
    if [ ! -z "$1" ];                            
    then
       if ! [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]];
        then
            echo "$1 is not a number"
            exit 2
        else echo "it's a number"
        fi
    fi
}

wait_some 2.2
```

The best thing about your error is even http://www.shellcheck.net/ couldn't identify the incorrect syntax in the `if-condition` and asserted the script didn't have any issues.

Comment: Note that the `-z` test isn't even necessary; you can try to match the empty string against the regular expression just fine. An empty string is not a number :)

Comment: @chepner : thanks for the comment. Didn't want to modify the author's code except the incorrect syntaxes. A lot of improvements are possible. :)

Comment: @chepner : Would like to know from greats like you if the explanation for questions like this are good enough. Would appreciate your suggestions! :)